# @if + lambda in an editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, razor, editortemplates

I have something for which I can't find the right syntax:

**/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Component.cshtml**

```
@model Website.Models.Component

<div class="editor-field">
    @if (x => x.Name == "")
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        <button class="create">New</button>
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
        <button class="delete" value="@Model.Id">X</button>
    }
</div>
```

I hope the intention is clear... how do I get there (it's hard to google for this sort of thing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x => x.whatever` is a lambda expression; it creates a delegate.

Inside an `if` condition, you need a normal expression, probably using the `Model` property:

```
@if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Model.Name)) {
```